# purpose of @ in urls without encoding

Tags: url

As I heard

> following symbols are reserved and can't be used without encoding in url.
> * ' ( ) ; : @ & = + $ , / ? % # [ ]

What's the real purpose of @without encoding in urls?
how it can be used?

Comment: Perhaps `mailto:webmaster@google.com`? Or in certain legacy HTTP Basic Authentication schemes: `http://admin:admin@192.168.1.1`?

Comment: Thanks @esqew for your wonderful reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [RFC2396](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt), it's a "reserved character":

> [ ... ] their usage within the URI component is limited to their reserved
> purpose.  If the data for a URI component would conflict with the
> reserved purpose, then the conflicting data must be escaped before
> forming the URI.

Though there is nothing **preventing** it from being used, so long as its use doesn't conflict with the intended purpose:

> The "reserved" syntax class above refers to those characters that are
> allowed within a URI, but which may not be allowed within a
> particular component of the generic URI syntax; they are used as
> delimiters of the components described in Section 3.

And section 3 states:

> The authority component is preceded by a double slash "//" and is
> terminated by the next slash "/", question-mark "?", or by the end of
> the URI.  Within the authority component, the characters ";", ":",
> "@", "?", and "/" are reserved.

So an `@` symbol is valid, so long as there are no query strings.

`@` is also valid for the `mailto` protocol, and for connecting directly to specified servers via an IP-based protocol (`<userinfo>@<host>:<port>`), though it may be omitted if not making use of user information:

> The parts "@" and ":" may be omitted.
> server        = [ [ userinfo "@" ] hostport ]

Comment: Thanks @Obsidian_Age for your wonderful reply. Your explanation gave clarity about this subject. Thanks from bottom of my heart